# ES6 Destructuring assignment with `this`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment, destructuring

The code below works. Is there a way that is more convenient, if possible even a one-liner?

```
const { nextUrl, posts } = await postService.getCommunityPosts(6);
this.communityPosts = posts;
this.nextUrl = nextUrl;
```

I know about giving destructured properties aliases but I don't think that helps in this case. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) doesn't say anything about that case.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can assign to the properties of an existing object by giving aliases and encapsulating the assignment in parentheses ([await codepen](https://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/rYdVzN?editors=1111)).

```js
const demo = { nextUrl: 'nextUrl', posts: 'posts' };

const target = {}; // replace target with this

({ nextUrl: target.nextUrl, posts: target.communityPosts } = demo);

console.log(target);
```

Comment: See [Is it possible to destructure instance/member variables in a JavaScript constructor? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127416/is-it-possible-to-destructure-instance-member-variables-in-a-javascript-construc) for the reason why the parentheses is necessary.

Comment: thanks.. i was wondering where the parenthesis was necessary..

Answer (score 12):

```js
function Person() {
  this.obj = {
    firstName: 'Dav',
    lastName: 'P'
  };

  ({firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName} = this.obj);
}

let p = new Person();

console.log(p);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that doesn't require duplicate property keys that `({key1: this.key1, key2: this.key2} = ...` does is to use `Object.assign()`.

```js
class X {
  constructor(properties) {
    ({...this} = properties); // Invalid destructuring assignment target
  }
}

x = new X({a: 3});
console.log(x);
```

```js
class X {
  constructor(properties) {
    Object.assign(this, properties);
  }
}

x = new X({a: 3});
console.log(x);
```