# ES6 destructuring whole object into this

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering if there's a way to use destructuring in order to copy all properties of an object into `this` without knowing the props.

```
class MyObject {
  constructor(data) {
    this.someFlag = true

    // How can I destructure 'data' into this.
  }
}
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47411063/3119050) answer (and some other) but they all have in common the knowledge of the properties to be copied or the usage of `Object.assign`. I'm wondering how to do it using simple destructuring.

Comment: Destructuring doesn't work if you don't know the properties? Not sure what you are trying to achieve, when your `Object.assign` solution already works.

Comment: Object.keys(data).forEach(key => this[key] = data[key])

Comment: @roliroli `Object.assign(this, data);`

Comment: @Bergi I'm just wondering whether is it possible to exploit destructuring operators to do this.

Comment: What would be the use in doing so? You would need to know the properties beforehand.

Comment: @FredMaggiowski `for (const k in data) {[k]: this[k]} = data` is the best I can think of that achieves what you need and still uses destructuring. There is no syntax to have a target for multiple properties.

Comment: @FredMaggiowski the only thing you can do with object destructuring, without knowing the properties, is making a shallow copy: `const { ...copy } = data;` of which you still don't know the properties. And NO, you can't put `this` in there, as `this` is no t a valid name for a variable.

Comment: You can use `{...this, ...data}` to merge the two objects but you can't redefine `this` to this value

Comment: @Kobe no actual use, I've recently started using javascript after a few years and now that I'm studying the new stuff they introduced with ES6 I'm having questions that needs to be answered :)

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about what @frobinsonj suggested in order to something like `this = {...this, ...data }` but felt dirty because it rewrites the entire `this`.

Comment: even with modern ES, `this = ...` is still not possible in JS.

Comment: @Thomas true, indeed..

Comment: *in modern JS* ... Why would `Object.assign` be old-fashioned? It works (great)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use destructuring, as that would be used in redefining `this` which you can't do. Either go with `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign(this, data);
```

Or if you *really* want to use destructuring some way or another:

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, v]) => this[k] = v);
```

Comment: That array destructuring is far fetched ;)

Comment: Thanks @JonasWilms (it's destructuring - 2 kinds ;P)